# How to find consecutive increase in stock price

Tags: sql

Given the following table

```
Stock_Ticker Date_id     Close_Price
AMZN         2021-05-01  3400
AMZN         2021-05-02  3410   
AMZN         2021-05-03  3405   
AMZN         2021-05-04  3450   
AMZN         2021-05-05  3460
AMZN         2021-05-06  3420
AMZN         2021-05-07  3421
AMZN         2021-05-08  3423
AMZN         2021-05-09  3440
AMZN         2021-05-10  3435
MSFT         2021-05-01  310
MSFT         2021-05-02  315
MSFT         2021-05-03  325
MSFT         2021-05-04  300
XYZ          2021-05-01  100
XYZ          2021-05-02  90
XYZ          2021-05-03  95
XYZ          2021-05-04  80
XYZ          2021-05-05  90
XYZ          2021-05-06  80
```

How do I find the stock with a continuous price increase for 2 consecutive days, along with the start date? I understand I have to use the LAG window function but not sure how I will be able to scale in to n consecutive days increase in price

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Answer (score 3):

You can set dynamically the number of days.
To include days with no price fluctuations, change `trend_min = 1` to `trend_min >= 0`.

```
with prm(days) as (select 2)

select  stock_ticker
       ,date_id
from    (       
        select  Stock_Ticker
               ,Date_id
               ,min(trend) over (partition by stock_ticker order by date_id rows between 1 following and (select days from prm) following) as trend_min 
        from   (select *
                      ,sign(Close_Price - lag(Close_Price) over (partition by stock_ticker order by Date_id)) as trend
                from   t
               ) t
        ) t
where   trend_min = 1
```

| stock_ticker | date_id |
| --- | --- |
| AMZN | 2021-05-03 00:00:00 |
| AMZN | 2021-05-06 00:00:00 |
| AMZN | 2021-05-07 00:00:00 |
| MSFT | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8043b9952cd5cb9b218d434f1aa0c1f6&hide=1)

Comment: See updated answer